# Reupload images on Amazon S3 carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-s3, carrierwave

I have images uploaded to `amazon s3 bucket`. When I tried to `recreate_versions!`, It gives me a `nil body` exception.

I think this is due to changes in previous uploader settings in our code. However, when I do `pr.image.url`, it still gives me the original image, so what I tried is below:

```
begin 
    User.all.each do |pr|
        if pr.user.present?
           pr.remote_avatar_url = pr.avatar.url
           pr.save!
        end
    end
    rescue
end
```

But it throws an error:

> ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Avatar trying to
>   download a file which is not served over HTTP

Which I know is carrierwave exception. What I'm trying to do is, I want to reupload all the images (because `pr.avatar.url` give me the original image), but I don't know how to do it. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You are [correct](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/How-to%3A-Validate-the-URL-for-remote-uploads) in attempting to store the remote URL in an attribute called remote_avatar_url.

CarrierWave throws the `Validation failed: ATTRIBUTE trying to download a file which is not served over HTTP` exception when attempting to save an invalid URL to the model. More specifically, `CarrierWave::Uploader::Download` raises a `CarrierWave::DownloadError` when the downloaded file "scheme" attribute does not match the regex /^https/ (meaning the URL does not start with "https"). You can view this logic [here](https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/7406960/). (In particular, see lines 31 and 69.)

I'm not sure if this is the problem, but you might try checking the `pr.avatar.url` to see whether it begins with the https prefix before assigning it to the `remote_avatar_url`.

I hope this was at least somewhat helpful.

Comment: that's the reason not the solution . right ? i already mentioned these things in my question in short way dear . :(

Comment: Sorry, I was just trying to help you diagnose the problem! Have you considered concatenating the https prefix to the `pr.avatar.url` before assigning it to `remote_avatar_url`? It's not a graceful solution, but it's worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

To re-upload the image, you need to download the image, if your carrierwave attr is `remote_avatar`, then maybe you can do something like:

```
begin 
  User.all.each do  |pr|
      if pr.user.present?
         pr.remote_avatar = File.open(pr.avatar.url, 'rb')
         pr.save!
      end
  end
rescue
end
```

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry. Try requiring `require 'open-uri'` and do directly `open('http://....')` (the function is `open` and not `File.open`)